# Launch another activity from my notification receiver

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Okay, so, I'll preface this by stating I'm using Titanium, so that'll, I assume, put a bad taste in your mouth. So, I'm sorry for my lack on knowledge on the Android side of things.

So, I've got a thing set up to receive GCM notifications. I can send them correctly to my app, and the code runs and tries to launch my app when it's clicked. However, it's just giving me this in the logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager(  307): START {act=com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x34000000 bnds=[0,102][720,230] u=0} from pid -1
W/InputMethodManagerService(  307): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@427a60a8 attribute=null
```

I got the C2DM receiving stuff from a third party, and I've tried to modify it to do what I need, but I'm clearly doing something not quite right.

Here's the onMessage:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(LCAT, "Message received");

    HashMap data = new HashMap();
    for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
        Log.d(LCAT, "Message key: " + key + " value: "
                + intent.getExtras().getString(key));

        String eventKey = key.startsWith("data.") ? key.substring(5) : key;
        data.put(eventKey, intent.getExtras().getString(key));
    }
    if (C2dmModule.getInstance() == null) {
        int icon = 0x7f020000; // get this from R.java
        CharSequence tickerText = "Geneca Journaling";
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        CharSequence contentTitle = "Rate your journal";
        CharSequence contentText = "Notification Content";
        String title = extras.getString("title");
        String message = extras.getString("message");
        if(title != null) {
            contentTitle = title;
        }
        if (message != null) {
            contentText = message;
        }

        //Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, C2DMReceiver.class);

        Intent launcherintent = new Intent("com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity");
        launcherintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.     FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        launcherintent
                .setComponent(ComponentName
                        .unflattenFromString("com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity"));
        launcherintent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");


        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                launcherintent, 0);

        // the next two lines initialize the Notification, using the
        // configurations above

        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);

        notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText,
                contentIntent);
        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    } else
        C2dmModule.getInstance().sendMessage(data);
}
```

Here's my manifest stuff (I think)

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <manifest>
        <activity android:name=".GenecaJournalingActivity"/>
        <permission
            android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
        <application>
            <service android:name="com.findlaw.c2dm.C2DMReceiver"/>
            <receiver
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                    <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                    <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        </application>
    </manifest>
</android>
```

There's also another manifest section in a different place, because of how Titanium handles things:

```
<android:manifest>
    <permission android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive message -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Send the registration id to the server -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- App must have this permission to use the library -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <activity android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity"/>

    <application>
           <!-- In order to use the c2dm library, an
               application must declare a class with the name C2DMReceiver, in its 
               own package, extending com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBaseReceiver

               It must also include this section in the manifest, replacing 
                "com.google.android.apps.chrometophone" with its package name. 
           -->
        <service android:name="com.findlaw.c2dm.C2DMReceiver" />

        <!-- Only google service can send data messages for the app. If permission is not set -
             any other app can generate it --> 
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

            <!-- Start receiver on boot -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Receive the actual message -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile" />
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- Receive the registration id -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.geneca.journaling.mobile" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>
</android:manifest>
```

If the app is already open, it runs some Titanium code, which I think I'll be able to figure out, but if the app is not open, it hits stuff in the onMessage which I can't quite figure out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
Intent launcherintent = new Intent("com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity");
```

Creates a new Intent with the action `com.geneca.journaling.mobile.GenecaJournalingActivity`.

Is this what you wanted?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.package.address","com.package.address.MainActivity"));
  startActivity(intent);
```

or

```
 Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Comment: It's not in the same application, I think. Titanium manages creating the java and compiling it for my main application, but I'm compiling the C2DM receiver separate from that, so GenecaJournalingActivity doesn't even exist in that context. (On a side note, I've decided in the future I'm not going to use Titanium...)

Comment: updated code. in any case, what I meant was that your action is incorrect.

Comment: Okay, so that gives me this error: `msg:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.geneca.journaling.mobile/com.geneca.journaling.mobile.MainActivity};`

Comment: Actually, that second one did it. Awesome. Now it's giving me something about an application restart required, but I think I've seen stuff about that elsewhere. Thanks!